# ValueError: Could not find function url in draco.apps.home.models

Tags: python, django, migration, django-models, django-migrations

I just extending my user model, adding fields like user, photo, phone, email. My problem arise when I make migration in console with   "./manage.py makemigrations" command. The complete message is:

```
ValueError: Could not find function url in dracoin.apps.home.models.
Please note that due to Python 2 limitations, you cannot serialize unbound method functions (e.g. a method declared
and used in the same class body). Please move the function into the main module body to use migrations.
```

Here my "models.py" (I believe that this .py is the origin of the mistake):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class userProfile(models.Model):

    def url(self,filename):
        ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/%s/%s"%(self.user.username,filename)
        return ruta

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=url)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I'm new in django and also in python, apologizeme in advance if I overlook something.

Thanks!!

Comment: Since it is a class method, you should be doing `upload_to=self.url`

Comment: @karthikr not true. `self` is not defined in that scope.

Comment: Oopss. No clue what I was thinking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message does in fact tell you what the problem is - that `url` in the definition of the `photo` field is a bound method, which can't be serialized - and it even gives you the solution, which is to move the method out of the class into the main function. It means this:

```
def url(obj, filename):
    ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/%s/%s"%(obj.user.username,filename)
    return ruta

class userProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=url)
```